# TypeScript type contains keys of another type but has different value types

Tags: typescript

If I have this const in which the values are all functions:

```
export const staffingReducers = {
    calendar: calendarReducer,
    navigation: navigationReducer,
    shifts: shiftsReducer,
};
```

I have an interface defined as such:

```
export interface StaffingState {
    calendar: CalendarState;
    navigation: NavigationState;
    shifts: ShiftState;
    selectedId: number;
}
```

I would like to enforce that my staffingReducers have all the same keys as the StaffingState. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Sure thing:

```
const staffingReducers: { [K in keyof StaffingState]: Function } = {
    calendar: calendarReducer,
    navigation: navigationReducer,
    shifts: shiftsReducer,
};
```

With your current code it will result in an error because `staffingReducers` doesn't have a property for `selectedId`.

You can find more info here: [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, I want the error! Thanks!